# Replace "Month Date Time" formatted dates with "Month Year Date Time" formatted dates in multiple files

Tags: macos, find-and-replace

I have some files in a directory that contain dates that are formatted like:

```
December 29 19:05:58
```

But they differ referring to the date that the file was created.

Is there any way to do a search-replace on these files to replace the dates with ones that look like:

```
December 29 2010 19:05:58
```

I am on Mac OS X.

EDIT: To clarify, any scripting would be fine, i.e: `sed` or shell/ruby scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without a powerful text editor or some scripting.

---

Use the following regular expression in TextMate:

Search:

```
(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (\d{1,2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

Replace with:

```
$1 $2 2010 $2
```

---

Depending on the number of files scripting would be faster. I'd opt for an editor like TextMate if it's not too much work -- this way, you get to check each substitution before you save.

---

For the sake of completeness:

```
cat src.txt | sed "s/\([A-Z][a-z]\{1,\} [0-9]\{1,2\}\) \([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)/\1 2010 \2/g" > dest.txt
```

People who use `sed` regularly may laugh now, I don't care.

Comment: Scripting is fine, so would `sed` work?

Comment: @Mark I'm not a `sed` user -- maybe wait a few minutes ;)

Comment: @DanielBeck: I think I'll try out the trial of TextMate for this purpose, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: You can use `\+` instead of `\{1,\}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (for OS X, replace the `-r` with `-E`):

```
sed -r 's/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)( [0-9 ][0-9] )(([0-9][0-9]:){2}[0-9][0-9])/\1\22010 \3/'
```

Comment: Wouldn't all these parentheses need escaping?

Comment: @Daniel: Not with `-r` or `-E`.